# Flutter : How to make the flutter chip grow and shrink to match the label length

Tags: flutter

I am creating a flutter chip where the label has  HTML text is tag (br) . I would like the label to break based on the "br tag and the chip widget size to reflect it.

Here my sample :

```
Chip(
  avatar: CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
    child: Text('AB'),
  ),
  label: HtmlWidget('You have pushed the button <br>this many times:'),
),
```

I am using the "flutter_widget_from_html_core" to render html.

The text wraps but the widget stay the same size

can you please let me know how to fix it or an alternative

example

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some issue with `HtmlWidget` improperly calculating the size in case of a line break.

A simple fix should work.

**EDIT:** This code is responsive as well, just pass `responsive:true`

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
        child: Text('AB'),
      ),
      label: ResponsiveBrTag(
        'You have pushed the button very hard <br> this many times:',
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ResponsiveBrTag extends StatelessWidget {
  final String htmlText;
  final bool responsive;
  const ResponsiveBrTag(this.htmlText, {this.responsive = false});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var splits = htmlText.split("<br>");
    var fixedLayout = Column(
      children: splits.map((s) => Text(s)).toList(),
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    );
    var respLayout = Wrap(children: splits.map((s) => Text(s)).toList());

    return responsive ? respLayout : fixedLayout;
  }
}
```

*Note: I have not completely tested it for bugs, it is just an example code.*

Comment: added a responsive layout as well as fixed layout.